# Использование getForObject для получения Json

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, jackson

Привет! Есть Json следующего вида:

```
[
  { 
    "id": 1, 
     "typeOfOrganization": "Администрации",
     "created_at": 1462136400000
  },
  {
     "id": 2,
     "typeOfOrganization": "Архив",
     "created_at": 1462136400000
   }
]
```

Из приложения пытаюсь получить его так:

```
return  template.getForObject(Constans.URL.GET_PUBLIC_ORG_ITEM, OrgDTO.class);
```

Но при запуске вываливается exception:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: Could not read JSON: Can not deserialize instance of com.spravka.dto.OrgDTO out of START_ARRAY token
```

Однако, если написать так:

```
OrgDTO[] result = template.getForObject(Constans.URL.GET_PUBLIC_ORG_ITEM, OrgDTO[].class);
return result[0];
```

Все нормально, но выводится соответственно первый элемент: typeOfOrganization - Администрации.

Что мне сделать, чтобы вывелся весь список? Подозреваю, что это из-за того, что json приходит в массиве [].

Comment: *Что мне сделать, чтобы вывелся весь список* - Возвращать не `result[0]`,а `result`?

Comment: @Nofte, подчеркивает красным return result. Cannot convert type of expression list from java.util.List<com.spravka.dto.OrgDTO> to java.util.List<com.spravka.dto.OrgDTO[]>

Comment: Ну так и сигнатуру метода поменяйте

Answer (score 1):

Очевидно, что ваш JSON это не представление класса OrgDTO, а коллекции объектов этого класса. Именно поэтому getForObject() не может распарсить JSON в один объект.

Как справедливо указал Nofate, вам нужно получить его как коллекцию, а уже из нее доставать нужный объект.

```
OrgDTO[] parseMyJSON() {
   OrgDTO[] result = template.getForObject(Constans.URL.GET_PUBLIC_ORG_ITEM, OrgDTO[].class);
   return result;
}
```

Или если метод не может меняться, то передавать ему не весь JSON, а лишь ту часть, которая представляет объект который вам нужен.